# Ajax load div, and then return to previous div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

The Title might say what i am needing.

Got it from a site..
Did it like this [LINK](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm)

I am very new in coding and all.

But is it possible that there is a piece of code, that i can return to the previous div?
Because right now when i press or click return it goes to the previous html page.

Thanks in advance!

```
var loadedobjects=""
var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname

function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
var page_request = false
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
try {
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
} 
catch (e){
try{
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
catch (e){}
}
}
else
return false
page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
loadpage(page_request, containerid)
}
page_request.open('GET', url, true)
page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
}

function loadobjs(){
if (!document.getElementById)
return
for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
var file=arguments[i]
var fileref=""
if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1){ //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
}
else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
fileref=document.createElement("link")
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
}
}
if (fileref!=""){
document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seems you want to keep a history of the state of a page after ajax calls.
the easy answer is to check out either YUI History Manager ( http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/ ) or jQuery history plugin ( http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/ )

Comment: Thanks, i now get it that it is not going to be solved with just a few lines of code XD. I will look into the developer Yahoo one, looks like its explained better there. Just want to say really like this site helping people out! Cheers from Holland!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to handle the back and forward buttons of your browser ?

This can be a pretty hard task, and many solutions / library / plugins exists to help with this.

For example you can have a look at : http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/

However, this will maybe need a major refactoring of your existing codebase, but without more informations, it's really hard to say.

Comment: I added the code if you meant more informatations. I looked in to the website you send but that goes way above my head. I want to use the ajax load in div for a portfolio page so that updating it would be easy. So there is not a simple solution for this...?